# CiviMail Mailing Scheduled But Not Sent

Tags: civimail, email

I have set up a mailing and scheduled it. The date and time has been and gone and the status is still scheduled... Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: I am on 5.25.0, PHP 7.2 and experiencing same issue. This is job log  Entity: Job Action: process_mailing
Summary
Starting execution of Send Scheduled Mailings
Details

Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message: 
Starting execution of Send Scheduled Mailings

Cron also seems to have worked previously and nothing changed so far. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that your cron isn't set up.  I would check to make sure that your Status Console (**Administer menu » Administration Console » System Status**) doesn't have a "Cron Not Running" message (check the hidden statuses if there are any!).

It's also possible that the Scheduled Job to send mailings hasn't been enabled. Check **Administer menu » System Settings » Scheduled Jobs** and ensure that *Send Scheduled Mailings* is enabled.  You can also see the last time it ran and ensure it matches your expectation from cron.

Finally, if the job DID run, click the **View Job Log** link next to the *Send Scheduled Jobs* record.  If you're not sure how to interpret the result, please edit your original question to include the log.